# The figure and the increment is not displaying when I click the button. Cross origin error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

The figure and the increment is not displaying when I click the button. When I click the button, the figure should appear and every time I click, the number should update according to 'add.php.' Console gives me an error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load...Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

I have looked at answers that have addressed the cross origin bug, however, I still do not know how to fix it. (Please don't downgrade me!)

I am using google chrome.

**index.html**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <p><a href = "add.php">Click to update score</a></p>
    </head>


    <body>
        <p id = "figure"></p>
        <button id = "like_btn">Like</button>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**add.php**

```
<?php
    // Connect to the database with '$mysqli' as the connection variable name
    $mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "friends");

    //Check connection
    // '$mysqli->connect_errno' = Returns the error code from last connect call
    // '->' is used to access an object method or property
    if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli -> connect_errno);
    }

     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 1");
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);



    $stmt = "UPDATE user SET score = (score + 1) WHERE id = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stmt);

    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stmt)) {
        echo $row['score'];
    }
    else {
        echo "failure";
    }
?>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#like_btn').click(function(){
        $("#figure").load("add.php");
    });

});
```

Comment: that's odd, Cross Origin usually means you are going to another site to 'borrow' their data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware that you're performing the UPDATE query twice?

`$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stmt);`

`if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stmt))`

Comment: You helped me a lot! I appreciate you noticing that!